# problem using math.random on array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I got a project in school to make a Sudoku game and i am  having a problem when trying to apply a random Sudoku from an array appear in the html
when i am using a not random sudoku it works fine, but when i use randomSudoku as the matrix it all messes up and gives me an entire array within each input

```
//this is the 9x9 matrix and there are 3 more
let sudoku1 = [
    [8, 2, 7, 1, 5, 4, 3, 9, 6],
    [9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 7, 1, 4, 8],
    [3, 4, 1, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2],
    [5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1],
    [4, 7, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9],
    [6, 1, 8, 9, 7, 2, 4, 3, 5],
    [7, 8, 6, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1, 4],
    [1, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6, 8, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 9, 8, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7]];
//these are the array of sudokus(each sudoku is a 9x9 matrix)
let allSudokus = [[sudoku1], [sudoku2], [sudoku3], [sudoku4]]
let randomSudoku = allSudokus[Math.floor(Math.random() * allSudokus.length)]

//this is the function i did in order to fill "solve" the board
const solveBoard = () => {
    for (let r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
        for (let c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            let cellid = document.querySelector("#r" + r + "c" + c); //
            cellid.innerHTML = randomSudoku[r][c]
        }
    }
}
```

[this is what happens when i use randomSudoku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxV36.png)

[this is when i use sudoku1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9kre.png)

Comment: Can you re-check your code as posted here? Your capitalization is not consistent ("allSudokus" vs "allsudokus"), and that makes a big difference in JavaScript.

Comment: Given that  the "allsudokus" typo is not the problem, it looks like there must be a problem with the contents of sudoku1, sudoku2, etc. We need to know what these contain to help further.

Comment: So sudoku1 works fine, but randomSudoku doesn't? Sounds like sudoku2, sudoku3, etc are the problem. There is no other reason for this to break unless you are running different code than what is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `allsudokus` (which doesn't exist) instead of `allSudokus`. Do this:

```
let randomSudoku = allSudokus[Math.floor(Math.random() * allSudokus.length)]
```

and then same here:

```
cellid.innerHTML = randomSudoku[r][c]
```

edit: ok you fixed that issue now

Comment: yea it was a writing mistake at my part , i already fixed the typo but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please see my other answer then